# Can't type in InputType 'text' in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

I am using NodeJS.

Here is my componenet in my coursePage.js. Ihe problem is that when I run it I can't type in my InputType, although I can't see any error in my code (neither the console shows me anything).

```
import React , {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as courseActions from '../../actions/courseActions';

class coursesPage extends React.Component{

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      course: {title: ""}
    };

    this.onTitleChange= this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.onClickSave= this.onClickSave.bind(this);
  }

  onTitleChange(event){
    const course = this.state.course;
    course.title = event.target.value;
    this.setState=({course: course});
  }

  onClickSave(){
    this.props.dispatch(courseActions.createCourse(this.state.course));
  }
  courseRow(course,index){
    return <div key = {index}>{course.title}</div>;
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Courses</h1>
        {this.props.courses.map(this.courseRow)}
        <h2>Add Course</h2>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.onTitleChange}
          value={this.state.course.title}/>

        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Save"
          onClick={this.onClickSave}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
coursesPage.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  courses: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps){
  return{
    courses : state.courses
  };

}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(coursesPage);
```

Comment: Maybe wrong `=` char after `setState`. `this.setState=({course: course});` should be just `this.setState({course: course});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this setState is like a function , so you use '=' maybe is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is, you are updating the `state` value in a wrong way, try this:

```
const course = this.state.course;
course.title = event.target.value;
this.setState({course});
```

To update the `state` value, we need to pass an `object` in `setState`, instead of assigning the `object`;

Comment: why downvote, now what is wrong in my answer, whosever is downvoting please provide a reason also, i am not an expert :), i think SO needs to provide the name also who is down voting the answer, so that we can ask that guy,  reason of downvote. If you think anyones answer is not good or needs an imporvement write that in comment or write your own answer, so that every one can learn something instead of just downvoting others answer and sit silently.

Comment: setState({course}) and setState({course: course}) are one and the same thing, there is virtually not difference. To clarify , I am not the one who downvoted

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri he was using `this.setState=({})`, check his ques, i suggested him `setState({})` with a small addition change, btw i didn't say why u down voted my answer :), i was asking for the reason, whosoever is downvoted this one :) i know you very well used to follow ur answers on SO :)